# AttributeError: 'LabeledPrice' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to add payment for my telegram bot(`pyTelegramBotAPI`).
But when I use [`payments_example.py` from GitHub](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/payments_example.py) - it gives exception:
`AttributeError: 'LabeledPrice' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`.

Can somebody help me with this?

```
shipping_options = [
    ShippingOption(id='instant', title='WorldWide Teleporter').add_price(LabeledPrice('Teleporter', 1000))
]


@bot.shipping_query_handler(func=lambda query: True)
def shipping(shipping_query):
    print(shipping_query)
    bot.answer_shipping_query(
        shipping_query.id,
        ok=True,
        shipping_options=shipping_options,
        error_message='Oh, seems like our Dog couriers are having a lunch right now. Try again later!'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem just now with `python-telegram-bot` version 13.5, while downgrading to 13.4.1 fixed the issue temporarily (via `pip3 install 'python-telegram-bot==13.4.1'`).

Happened on Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8.5.